# [WP7][MVVM Light toolkit] Button Command raised too early, before binding when using mvvm-light toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm using the mvvm-light toolkit in my windows phone 7 application.

I have in my view :

```
<TextBox Height="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="313" Text="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button Content="Go" Height="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,252,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding DoCommand}"  />
```

My view model is :

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand DoCommand { get; internal set; }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        DoCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                DoSomethingWith(MyValue);
            }, () => true);

    }

    private const string MyValuePropertyName = "MyValue";
    private string _myValue;
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return _myValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_myValue == value)
                return;
            _myValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyValuePropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

In the emulator, when I type value in the textbox, and I click the button, I can see that I'm going first in the relaycommand lambda expression and with a breakpoint
I see that MyValue is null. Then, the breakpoint in the setter of MyValue is reached, and the correct value goes in MyValue.

What am I doing wrong ? Of course, I would like that the setter can be reached before the RelayCommand...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you have hit the TextBox DataBinding issue with the TextChanged event. This is a recognized problem in Silverlight 3, [see this thread discussing this issue](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/51100/484129.aspx) and the workaround. A neat solution is perhaps to use behaviors as discussed in [this article](http://zoltanarvai.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/binding-update-on-textbox-textchanged-event-using-behaviors/).

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: thanks for your answer. you are talking about SL 3, but I'm using SL4, this changes something ?

Comment: Note that Windows Phone 7 Silverlight is Silverlight 3 with some bits from Silverlight 4. Have a look at this post - http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2010/03/16/Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7-is-NOT-the-same-full-Silverlight-3-RTM.aspx, there are other posts discussing the Silverlight version on the WP7